How to make a subpackage available to import without specifying the root package
My demo project structure:
project_root_directory
├── pyproject.toml
└── src/
    └── root/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module.py
        │
        ├── nested_a/
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── ...
        │   └── module.py
        │
        └── nested_b/
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── ...
            └── module.py

The content of pyproject.toml is the simplest:
[project]
dependencies = []
description = "Friends"
name = "demo"
requires-python = ">=3.11"
version = "0.0.1"

[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = [ "setuptools",]

[[project.authors]]
name = "Ross Geller"


According to docs an automatic discovery is enabled.
It make me available to import packages from anywhere as follows:
import root

import root.nested_a
import root.nested_a

import root.nested_a.module
import root.nested_b.module

So far, so good. But in some real projects I'd like to do something that:
import root

import nested_a
import nested_b

import nested_a.module
import nested_b.module

How to achieve that?
And another one extra feature to me: "aliases" for packages
import my_pretty_root_name  # instead of import root

But real package name must be still available:
import my_pretty_root_name  # instead of import root
import root  # also works

It is possible? (without changing names of directories)
I've read the docs, but I got stuck.

You can do import root as my_pretty_root_name, but what would be the point of having one package with two names?

You can certainly have root.__init__.py add its own directory to the Python path.  You might consider whether that's really wise.  People need to know where their names come from.
